# Errors installing pip package manager for python 3.4 on Mac OSX

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, python-3.4

I'm trying to install pip for python 3.4. Here's the error message that I get.

```
python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory
```

The python version information of my system is hereunder:

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This is my path

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

How do I install pip and then virtualenv. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting the Python 3.4 `bin` directory at the end of your `PATH`, running `python` in Terminal is resulting in `/usr/bin/python` being called, which is the system version 2.6. Try just running `python` and you'll see.

To fix it, set your `PATH` up like so:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

`2.7/bin` contains a `python` executable, while `3.4/bin` should also contain a `python3` executable. Now, when you run `python` from the command prompt, the Python.org version of Python 2.7 will start up, and if you run `python3` then version 3.4 will start. Download `get-pip.py` from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then run it using `python3`. Depending on your system configuration, you may need to prefix the command with `sudo` (i.e., `sudo python3 get-pip.py`).

Python 3.4 already comes with [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), so you should be able to run `pyvenv /path/to/virtual_env` to set up a virtual environment.

Comment: How do I download get-pip.py since the link goes to a page full of binary data.

Comment: @Clockwork - when I click on the link it automatically asks to save the file. If that's not working for you, try right-clicking on the link and selecting **`Save Link As...`** or **`Download Target As...`** or whatever the wording is for your browser.

Comment: 08:46:51 >> sudo python3 get-pip.py 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
But I continue to get command not found.

Comment: @Clockwork first run `hash -r` to refresh bash's search directory hash, then try running `pip3` instead.